# How do I create a test room for modeling and simulations?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials, photorealism

How do I create a low poly room with one door and one window in clean white style that looks nice.

I want to have a clean testing room to mainly test simulations in and also test materials for models.

The biggest problem I have is to create a node for the texture, I don't want to use a bitmap texture because they create unnecessary problems when rescaling the room for things like planes.

I do want it to at least look like it is a photo when the image is compressed as a jpg

This is kinde of what i whant.
[image]


This is what I have.
[image]
The two bigest problem I have is that it is grey and the flore feels un-natural.


This is the best I did get by editing the light. I did set the exposuer to 2, sampling to Final and light path to Full Global Illumination.
[image]
It is very low in detail in the corners.

[image]

Comment: What have you got so far, where exactly are you stuck in your workflow? Please focus your question on specific technical problems that you encounter. As it stands this question is too broad and very opinion based, more suited for a forum format like https://blenderartists.org or other online communities

Comment: A low poly room with clean style... very vague...  that looks "nice" Your notion of nice might not be the same as anybody else's... Are you asking about modeling the room or about nodes for texturing? Is the question about scaling a texture? Is the question about photorealism? about image compression? How are we supposed to know what you have imagined? Please edit your post. make it a single clear question and make the title reflect that as well.

Comment: I have fixed both of you'r requests. White clean like the white rooms in Resident Evil is not a broad description if you have seen them. A short god answer now, should not need to be longer than two paragraphs.

Comment: It would suggest adding more light to the room since it looks quite dark at the moment. And maybe add a bump map to the floor so it looks a bit less flat.

Comment: I'v uploaded the prodject